# Sort Tuples without using Python's built-in Sort

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I'm trying to merge this 2 tuples (t,n), so it returns a tuple that is the sorted combination of t and n.

Can't find what's wrong with this:

```
def junta(t,n):
    a = ()
    b = () 
    minimo = t[0]  
    for x in t: 
        if x < minimo:
            minimo = x
    a = a + (minimo)
    t = t - (minimo)
    minimo2 = n[0]  
    for y in n: 
        if y < minimo2:
            minimo2 = y
    b = b + (minimo2)
    n = n - (minimo2)
    c = a + b
    return c
```

This should do the same as this:

```
def  juntas(a,b):
    return tuple(sorted(a+b))
```

Comment: Do you mean (blah,) instead of (blah) to create a length 1 tuple?

Comment: Please properly indent your code.

Comment: you should post the error message that you get, which I assume is `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple` (and once you fix that one, you'll get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to your answers, i got to a solotion:

```
def junta(t,n):
a = ()
b = ()
d =()
while len(t)>0: 
    minimo = t[0]  
    for x in t: 
        if x < minimo:
            minimo = x
    a = a + (minimo,)
    minimo_index = t.index(minimo)
    t = t[:minimo_index] + t[minimo_index+1:]
while len(n)>0:
    minimo2 = n[0]  
    for y in n: 
        if y < minimo2:
            minimo2 = y
    b = b + (minimo2,)
    minimo2_index = n.index(minimo2)
    n = n[:minimo2_index] + n[minimo2_index+1:]
c = a + b
while len(c)>0:
    minimo3 = c[0]  
    for z in c: 
        if z < minimo3:
            minimo3 = z
    d = d + (minimo3,)
    minimo3_index = c.index(minimo3)
    c = c[:minimo3_index] + c[minimo3_index+1:]
return d
```

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis operator has two conflicting meanings: one of them is as a grouping operator. The other one is a tuple creation. `(minimo)` in your code means evaluate minimo with higher precedence. You want`(minimo,)` to create a 1-length tuple.

Comment: I was thinking in removing the minimum number of t and put him in the position 0 of a and repeat and in the end get everything together with a +

Comment: Tuple is created by comma, not parenthesis, except for a special case of empty tuple ().